# Fallback for jquery CDN not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cdn, fallback

I have the following jQuery CDN fallback on a test page. I am testing locally with chrome and IE. The CDN is not loading. If I use the `http://` in the CDN it loads, but if I remove it and just use `//` This makes no sense to me. If the script doesn't load the conditional statement should load it locally, but it's not. If I replace the

```
document.write('<script src="/scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"><\/script>')
```

with

```
document.write('undefined')
```

then I get the word undefined on the page after about 5 seconds. Am I not scaping properly? Here is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
(window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js">
 <\/script>'));
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert( "welcome" );
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW if I gave the page long enough, the local file would eventually kick in and run the alert with no problems SO my problem was imply the way I was linking to the CDN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be loading the page using the `file://` protocol. The exact meaning of the `//` protocol is "use the same protocol that I am using". If you are looking at `file://C:/Users/Me/test.html`, then your `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js` becomes the URI `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js` which is not a valid file path on your computer. If you want to test locally you need to either use the `http://` protocol in the link or host the project on IIS or apache on your box.

Comment: Ah I see, it's a local file system problem. I f I were running this on the server IIS or APache it would work. Is that right?

Comment: Correct, if you were running it locally your URI would be `http://localhost/test.html` and the `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js` would correctly become `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js`.